# Right-adjoint functors are left-exact?

Tags: category-theory, modules, adjoint-functors

As a final exercise to VIII.1 in Algebra: Chapter $0$, we are asked to prove

> If $\mathcal{F}\colon\operatorname{R-Mod}\to\operatorname{S-Mod}$ is a right-adjoint functor, then $\mathcal{F}$ is left-exact.

I am having some trouble proving this. If my overall strategy is right, then one necessary step is to show \begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(0)=0,
\end{equation} where $0$ is the zero module. However I do not know how to do this.

Can someone give a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271010/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As other have stated, there are lots of good properties for adjoint functors. I will just prove your $F(0)=0$ statement. Let $G$ be left adjoint par to $F$. Then for all $S$-modules $X$ and $R$-modules $Y$ we have bijection $Hom_R(GX,Y) \simeq Hom_S(X,FY)$. Put $Y=0$ and $X=F0$. So we get:

$$Hom_S(F0,F0) \simeq  Hom_R(GF0,0) \simeq \{0\}.$$

Now, if $F0\neq 0$, then there would be at least two different S-module-homomorphisms $F0 \to F0$ (namely, identity and zero-homomorphism), which would be a contradiction.

Answer (score 27):

As Martin Brandenburg mentioned, this holds in a much more general context:

Let $C,D$ be categories and $F\colon C\rightarrow D$, $G\colon D\rightarrow C$ functors, such that $F$ is left adjoint to $G$.
Then $F$ preserves all colimits and $G$ preserves all limits. Especially G preserves kernels and therefore is left-exact, whenever you can talk about exactness. (Dually: F preservers cokernels, so it's right-exact.)

This isn't hard to prove: You can prove by hand (checking the universal property), that covariant homfunctors $Hom(A,\_)$ preserve finite limits and then you can do the following by using the adjointness and the preservation of limits of hom-functors:

$$Hom(A,G(lim(X_i)))\cong Hom(F(A),lim(X_i))\cong lim(Hom(F(A),X_i))\cong lim(Hom(A,G(X_i)))\cong Hom(A,lim(G(X_i)))$$

All these isomorphisms are natural in A, so we get $Hom(\_,G(lim(X_i))\cong Hom(\_,lim(G(X_i)))$ and with the fact, that the Yoneda embedding is an embedding $G(lim(X_i))\cong lim(G(X_i))$. Dually this works for rightadjoints and colimits.

Comment: Not only finite limits. All limits.

Comment: This is proposition 3.3.6 in "Categories and sheaves" by Kashiwara and Schapira: functors admitting left adjoints are left-exact, and vice versa.  Also the content of 3.3.3 is that a functor is left-exact iff it commutes with _finite_ projective limits (when the category admits them).  Note that they define left-exact functors $F : \mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}'$ as those such that, for every $U \in \mathcal{C}'$, the category $\mathcal{C}^U$ (whose objects are pairs of objects $X \in \mathcal{C}$ and morphisms $v : U \to F(X)$) is _cofiltrant_.

Comment: @archipelago Right adjoints preserve _all_ limits that exist. Not just finite, not just small, _all_ of them.

Comment: @Adeel Generally we take left exact to mean preserves finite limits instead of the strong version you quote.

Comment: @ZhenLin Which reference would you recommend, that has this correct definition?

Comment: @archipelago: Your proof works for all limits, right?

Comment: @Adeel The stronger definition is in some sense the better one, but it is also more than what is needed usually.

Comment: Yes, I know right-adjoint functors preserves limits, but how can we show it preserves kernels? Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223824/when-are-kernels-resp-cokernels-finite-limits-resp-finite-colimits

Comment: I was struggling to prove the original statement for kernels.. for a whole morning. And then I gave up and bumped into this answer... so beautiful and elegant!!

Answer (score 2):

To prove that a right-adjoint *additive* functor is left-exact, use the adjunction isomorphism to build a commutative rectangle from some exact sequence and then use the fact that the [Yoneda embedding reflects exactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98877/the-yoneda-embedding-reflects-exactness-is-a-direct-consequence-of-yoneda).

I'm unsure about the [more general](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/exact+functor) setting. Although in that case you would need to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ preserves finite limits, which includes preserving terminal objects, i.e. $\mathcal{F}(0)=0$.

Comment: Exact functors are defined between arbitrary categories. Left exact = preservation of finite limits, right exact = preservation of finite colimits, exact = left exact and right exact.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I see. Although in the notes linked by the OP exact functors are defined as functors preserving exact sequences, and from [here](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/exact+functor#Definition) it looks like this implies your definition just for Ab-enriched, i.e. abelian, functors. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, it implies the "exact-sequence-definition", as I mentioned it in my answer. Kernels are limits and cokernels are colimits, whenever you can talk about kernels and cokernels. (e.g. in abelian categories)

Comment: It seems to me you have to first assume that the functor is additive, but in the exercise we only know it is right-adjoint. Is additivity necessary?

Comment: Not in general. Please see archipelago's nice answer.